# Copy Text From Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I would like to copy a text from iframe and put it in an "input" .
I search a java script function which can do that.

```html
<iframe src="www.mywebsite.com" ></iframe>
 <button  onclick="function();">Paste</button>
  <input id="paste"/>
```

Comment: You answer is below. Take it or close your Qn. You have not done enough research it seems

Answer (score 0):

If You want to take data from an IFrame from the parent Page, It is not possible.
This is intended as a security feature. 
You cannot take data from a website inside the IFrame in the parent PAge.

Comment: Thank you , i ll search another solution .